# How to marshal an unknown length C++ string to C# using its pointer?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to marshal a dynamically allocated char array in a struct to C#. The struct has a pointer to the array. The problem is the char array contains multiple null terminated strings and the last string is terminated by two consecutive null chars.

If I try to marshal it as `LPStr` I will get only de first string in the "list".

I tried using UnmanagedMemoryStream but it requires to know the length of the array.

Is there a way to read the bytes as a stream without knowing the length of the array? (Aside from using a n length byte buffer and keep increasing the pointer until two consecutive null terminating chars are found).

Comment: This sounds like there should be no problem with calculating string length.

Comment: You have to marshal it yourself.  Declare the struct member as IntPtr.  Loop with Marshal.ReadByte() to copy into a byte[], At a 0 use Encoding.Default.GetString() to convert the sub-string.  Until you find the second 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Hans Passant, the only way is to `Marshal.ReadByte()`, so in the end you have to read the memory multiple times (`PtrToStringAnsi` reads it at least twice plus the one we do to find where the next string begins).

```
public static string[] IntPtrToStringArrayAnsi(IntPtr ptr)
{
    var lst = new List<string>();

    do
    {
        lst.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr));

        while (Marshal.ReadByte(ptr) != 0)
        {
            ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
        }

        ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, 1);
    }
    while (Marshal.ReadByte(ptr) != 0);

    // See comment of @zneak
    if (lst.Count == 1 && lst[0] == string.Empty)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }

    return lst.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Beware that there is a corner-case, the first string might be empty.  You must loop at least once.  Consider do-while.

Comment: @HansPassant Had to invert both `while`/`do while`

Comment: I'm not OP, but it seems to me that if the "first string" is empty (the entire string is `\0\0`), then it should return an empty list.

Comment: @zneak The API I'm using states that in that case a null pointer will be returned. However it's a good call for a general algorithm.

Comment: @CesarHernandez In the end this format of array of strings doesn't support empty strings: `"a\0\0b\0"` will be considered to be `"a\0\0"`, so trimming `"\0\0"` to an empty array is consistant to the format.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate version, which avoids a second sweep over the array

```
private static List<string> IntPtrToStringArrayAnsi(IntPtr ptr)
{
    var lst = new List<string>();
    while (true)
    {
        var str = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            lst.Add(str);
            ptr += str.Length + 1;
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    return lst.ToArray();
}
```