# Marshalling char** of zero-terminated strings

Tags: c#, marshalling

The signature of the c-function is

```
void func(char** names)
```

After calling `func`, `names` points to an array which consists of consecutive zero-terminated strings like "foo1\0foo2\0...fooN\0\0".

**Q** How can I marshal the `char**` to an `IEnumerable<string>` or something similar?

Comment: I don't think this is a c++ question...

Comment: Same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51218293/17034).  Do beware you are pretty likely to have a memory leak, call it a gazillion time in a test program to ensure the memory usage does not explode.

Comment: @AlexF After two consecutive "\0\0" the show is over.

Comment: Knowing that this format is quite similar to how `REG_MULTI_SZ` is done in the registry, you could look at how the .NET code for [reading these values from the registry works](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/microsoft/win32/registrykey.cs,1318). Turns out there's no quick trick (and you'd still need to work out the length first before copying to a `char[]`)